# I am trying to add the average of the scores input from the score entity

Tags: jpa

In the score table, there is a score column and an avg column. I want to put the total average of scores input into socre into avg.   I've tried it, but I don't know what's wrong

````
@Table(name = "Score")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Score.findByUserName"
        , query = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(p.score),2) FROM Score p where p.score = :avg"
)  
public class Score {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private double Score;
    private double avg;
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to put total average..."?
Are you trying to use the query before persisting your entity into the database?

Comment: Whenever a score is saved, it is saved in the DB score column. I want to save and update the average of the cumulative scores stored in the db score in the avg column.

Comment: I want to store both the scores being saved and the total average for the accumulated scores being saved. Maybe the way I'm doing it isn't right??